# Google inApp onPurchaseStatechange

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing the Google in app purchase in my app. I downloaded the code from the Google side and run it in my app. first time i got an error of "Signature Verification Failed" I resolved it by building my app in release version , signing it and and published it on Google android market as unpublished app. Now at that sage when I buy the app and press the accept button and purchase it I received a response but the data is not stored in onPurchseState. and again the app gives that for downloading this app you have to purchase it. Any help will be appreciate. Here is the detail code

I'm calling requestPurchase(String productId, String payload) from the onClick method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == requestPurchaseButton) {
        mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", "10");
    }
}
```

The callback method onRequestPurchaseResponse(Request, ResponseCode) is called. The responseCode here gives the value RESULT_OK. So the request has been sent to the server.

```
   @Override
   public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request,
            ResponseCode responseCode) 
   {
          if(responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("My APP", "onRequestPurchaseResponse.ResponeCode.RESULT_OK");

      } else if(responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_USER_CANCELED) {

      } else { 

      }
   }
```

But the callback method

```
@Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState,
            String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime,
            String developerPayload) {
        Log.d("PucrchedState", "onPurchaseStateChanged");

    }
```

is never called.

Comment: Not clear what the problem is, give some details about he actual problem. Also you might want to try the recently released In-App Billing v3, it is easier to integrate and understand.

Comment: @Nikolay Elenkov i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPurchaseStateChange()` is called asynchronously and it might take some time (typically within seconds). However, the response might get lost or delayed if your device is behind a firewall, make sure nothing is blocking incoming connections (check if Google Talk works). Also make sure you have registered the corresponding `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest.